# Why I can't set the value with setState using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I try to set the value the `currentRole` is highlighted red. I attached a screenshot below.

```
const Container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentRole = useReduxSelector(state => state.auth.currentRole);
    setRole(currentRole);
  }, [role]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>lakjselkjaflkje</div>
      {children}
      {role}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error image see the picture:

[image]

Comment: `setRole(currentRole ?? undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make either *one* of these changes to make the types compatible:

```ts
const [role, setRole] = useState<string>();
// ...
setRole(currentRole ?? undefined);
```

```ts
const [role, setRole] = useState<string | null>(null);
// ...
setRole(currentRole);
```